# Activation link missing from activation email

Tags: users, emails

A client is reporting that users are attempting sign up but receiving activation emails with no activation link present, simply a blank space where the {{link}} tag is placed.

We are unable to re-create the issue at our end. Domain name settings have been verified, we are only using one domain and prefix (www diverts to non-www address).

In the screenshot below, the link shouls appear after 'following link:'

```
<p><strong>To activate your account, please click the following link, or copy-paste it into your browser:</strong></p>
<p class="activation-link"><strong>{{link}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>When the site opens, simply log in to view the Option Grids</strong></p>
```

Has anyone had any similar issues?

[image: email screenshot]

Comment: Did they forward you one of those emails? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Weird... if you view the email message body as plain text, do you see the same?

Comment: @BradBell at my end I see the link either way, it's very confusing, I'm only aware of the issue from reports of users forwarding the broken emails to my client on their side - it's intermittent there too and evidently works the majority of the time

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I found your site in question and registered for an account to test it. The plain text part of the e-mail is actually being sent down as HTML. Like you mentioned, it's prob up to the user agent to render it. Had an ancient version of Mac OS X mail handy;  when viewed in its plain text mode, it just showed the HTML markup as expected  and the link was clearly visible so probably not a Craft problem but you should put up a plain txt version. Wonder if other UAs are stripping the markup and the  URL ends up being a casualty too? Could be an anti-spam thing as well...

Comment: Is it a particular email client/version it's happening consistently on? Or more of a random thing with the same client.